# Using Anti-Aliased fonts in WinCe

Tags: windows-ce

I am developing an Application on WinCe, exactly Windows embedded coampact 7, using Visual Studio 2008, C# 3.5, .net Compact Framework 3.5. 
Now the designer told me, he needs Anti-Aliased fonts. Does anybody know how to enable anti-Aliasing on WEC7? Do I have to make a specific Plattform Build. Does it need a lot of Performance. Device is quite weak.

Thank you very much for any hint.

Answer (score 1):

Check this article. It's for CE 6 but applies also to Compact 7:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehall/archive/2009/04/17/enabling-cleartype-on-windows-ce-6-0.aspx